# Ln Det Matrix Calculus

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

Consider the following matrix derivative problem:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbb{X}}\ln\bigg(\det\Big(\mathbb{X}^T\mathbb{A}\mathbb{X}\mathbb{B}\Big)\bigg)=?$

where:

- $\mathbb{X}$  is a $(p\times d)$ semi-orthogonal matrix
- $\mathbb{A}$ is a $(p\times p)$ symmetric matrix
- $\mathbb{B}$ is a $(d\times d)$ symmetric matrix

I have checked a number of resources such as matrix Cookbook, but I cannot find any property such as this.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: A log is not making task more complicated, so all you need is know how to evaluate derivative of det(...), this trace of some matrices. If I had have to solve such a thing, I would have tried to start from det() or even some traces and then recover full answer from that.

Comment: X-post: http://mathoverflow.net/q/262801/91764

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$\eqalign{
 Y &= X^TAXB \cr
}$$
Then write the function in terms of $Y$ and find its gradient 
$$\eqalign{
 f &= \log\det Y \cr
\cr
df &= d\log\det Y = d\operatorname{tr}\log Y\cr
   &= Y^{-T}:dY \cr
   &= Y^{-T}:(dX^T\,AXB+X^TA\,dX\,B) \cr
   &= Y^{-T}B^TX^TA^T:dX^T + A^TXY^{-T}B^T:dX \cr
   &= AXBY^{-1}:dX + A^TXY^{-T}B^T:dX \cr
   &= \big(AXBY^{-1} + A^TXY^{-T}B^T\big):dX \cr
\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} &= AXBY^{-1} + A^TXY^{-T}B^T \cr
\cr
}$$ where I've used a colon to denote the double-dot (aka Frobenius) product in the intermediate steps.